# Checking cluster status in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have setup 3 nodes cluster in my LAB. Is there any command to check cluster status for all 3 servers except admin UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use `./yb-admin -init_master_addrs <master-ip-address:port> list_all_masters`  and `./yb-admin -init_master_addrs <master ip address> list_all_tablet_servers` which give the cluster status for all servers.